# Xtend's _field naming and SpringData's repository naming conventions

Tags: java, spring-data, xtend

It seems that the naming conventions between Xtend and Spring Data are incompatible.

For example:

```
// User.xtend
class User {
    @Property
    var Long id;
 }

 interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User> {
     public User findById(Long id)
 }
```

The `@Property` annotation renames `id` to `_id`, which causes Spring Data to fail, claiming `No property id found`

Is there a way to either:

- Suppress Xtend's renaming of the field
- "Teach" Spring Data about the naming convention (Looking for a field?  Add an underscore)
- Instruct Spring Data to use property-access, rather than field-access for the property resolution?

Any of these would solve this issue, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2.7.3 the @Property annotation has been superceded by @Accessors, which no longer prepends the fields with an underscore.

Before 2.7.3 you have to build your own @Property annotation which doesn't prepend an underscore to the field's name.

See http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/documentation.html#activeAnnotations

(updated)

Comment: I just want to point out that the `@Property` annotation has been deprecated and replaced by `@Accessors`. I also found this nice article about best practices for writing active annotations. http://mnmlst-dvlpr.blogspot.de/2013/06/active-annotation-best-practices.html